# only single record is returned by mysql loop query

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql loop concept and making my query to execute multiple times expecting a result  of multiple rows..

My query is:

```
DELIMITER $$    

CREATE FUNCTION getActiveLife(endTime INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE y INT;
    DECLARE c1 INT;
    SET x = endTime;
    SET y = 4;
    sloop:LOOP
       SELECT count(*) INTO c1 FROM `accounts` where (`life` != 'EXPIRED') and (`lifeEnd` <= x );
       IF y > 0 THEN
          SET x = x-3600;
          SET y = y - 1;
       ELSE
           LEAVE sloop;
       END IF;  
    END LOOP;
    RETURN c1;
END  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am actually trying to get the results from now to last 4 hours.... It has executed successfully but when i called it as below

```
SELECT getActiveLife(1368193391)...
```

It gives me one record with value as 1... Doesnt know what that means ....

Because when i execute

```
SELECT count(*) INTO c1 FROM `accounts` where (`life` != 'EXPIRED') and (`lifeEnd` <= 1368193391 );
```

It gives me count as 4...

so i am expecting something like 4 for loop1 ,2 for loop2 and so on in a table format.

If I am going wrong or missing something just correct me....

I am expecting something like:

```
  Result:
    4  - row1
    2  - row2
    1  - row3
```

In any form

Thank You.

Comment: You only have a single INT variable `c1` that you overwrite in the loop and then return it. I don't know why you think you should get a result set. If you are trying to get records within last few hours, I don;t understand the need for a loop.

Comment: may be i misunderstood it...  is there a way to return a table as result..

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this query would do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  SUM(1) AS `endtime_count`,
  SUM(IF(`lifeEnd` <= (? - (1 * 3600)), 1, 0)) AS `endtime_minus_1hour_count`,
  SUM(IF(`lifeEnd` <= (? - (2 * 3600)), 1, 0)) AS `endtime_minus_2hour_count`,
  SUM(IF(`lifeEnd` <= (? - (3 * 3600)), 1, 0)) AS `endtime_minus_3hour_count`,
  SUM(IF(`lifeEnd` <= (? - (4 * 3600)), 1, 0)) AS `endtime_minus_4hour_count`
FROM `accounts`
WHERE
  `life` <> 'EXPIRED'
  AND `lifeEnd` <= ?
```

Here we just use `IF` statements to sum up the counts you are looking for. Note that `?` represents the end time value you are querying against.

This would return a single row with all your values.

Comment: It worked really great... but its becoming bit lengthy when i want to calculate for last 12 hours or last 24 hours..... is there any way around it.. cause sometime the last number of hours is decided dynamically....

Comment: If that is the case, I would take a totally different approach and actually group the records results by hour and then doing any necessary summing in the application layer.  I would also change my database field to be a datetime field to make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is only returning one value (`return c1`).  It is returning the last value from the loop.

In MySQL, functions do not returns tables.  If you want four rows, then you need to execute a query.  Or, you could concatenate all the values together into a string, and return that.  What do you want this function to do?